# how to insert multiple row in form method using for loop in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am written the code for CREATE Operation in view which will insert multiple of rows in database using form-tag with for-loop. when click on Create button it will save only one row so i want that when i click on button no.of row should be created.

here code for View..

```
@model CarParking.Models.Area


@for (int i = 1; i <= Model.NoOfParkingPlaces; i++)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ParkingPlace", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <label>AreaID:</label>
        <input id="AreaID" name="AreaID" type="text" value="@Model.AreaID" />

        <label for="Parking_IDs">Parking IDs</label>
        <input type="text" value="P.Id: @i" name="PlaceId" />

        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    }
}
```

here code for Controller...

```
public ActionResult Create(string areaName)
    {
        Area area = db.Areas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ParkingPlaceName == areaName);
        return View(area);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ParkID,PlaceId,CarID,AreaID")] ParkingPlace parkingPlace)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ParkingPlaces.Add(parkingPlace);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(parkingPlace);
    }
```

Here some images how my View looks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx9Vw.png)

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes no sense at all. Please revise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to post ALL the forms on the page at once?

If so - it doesn't work like that... One option would be to use javascript to AJAX post them all, but the correct way to do it is to use one form, with each of the ParkingPlaces in it.

This article goes through it in detail: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

```
@for( int i = 0; i < Model.NoOfParkingPlaces; ++i)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ParkingPlaces[i].AreaId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ParkingPlaces[i].Id)  
    ... etc
}
```

and your action parameters become;

```
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<ParkingPlace> ParkingPlaces)
{
```